# Replace string by matching using regular expression python

Tags: python, regex

Original String:

```
necessary information Leave a Comment unnecessary information
```

Required String:

```
necessary information
```

I have multiple strings that are in the above mentioned 'Original String' format. I want to remove the 'Leave a Comment' and 'unnecessary information'.

Since 'Leave a Comment' is common in all string so I can build a Regular Expression on that? And use that in

```
string.replace( string , pattern )
```

The pattern here will be a Regular Expression. How can I write a RE for this?

Comment: Where is this input coming from? Is this a result of an HTML parsing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> s
'necessary information Leave a Comment unnecessary information'
>>> re.sub(r'\sLeave a Comment.*', '', s)
'necessary information'
```